# Using Chart.js to draw graphs from form fields

Tags: wordpress, chart.js, gravityforms

So I have a form in wordpress using Gravity forms. I have 100 fields. 10 fields per dataset. I want to add the values in each field for each dataset and then plot the graph on the results page.So let's take a piece of this code:

```
    <canvas  id="chart-01" width="700" height="400"  style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00);border-radius:0px;width:700px;height:400px;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px"></canvas>
    <script> function MoreChartOptions(){} 
  var ChartData = {
labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July",],
datasets : [
    {
    data : [65,8,90,81,56,55,40,],
    backgroundColor :'#3498db',
    borderColor : 'rgba(136,136,136,0.5)',
    label:"2013"},
```

I want to get the data from Gravityform's Getfieldvalue method and then show a sum like this:

```
    data : [filed1+field2+field3..field10,filed11+field12+field13..field20,.....]
```

Would be awesome if anyone can point me in the direction to get this done.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: I did a demo a while back with chart.js, passing data via html inputs, here is the link [that might help you](https://codepen.io/amarinediary/pen/PvBOJy?editors=1010)

Comment: Just thinking outloud, if you want to pass data from one page to an other the easiest thing to do would be to use localStorage to setItem and saving on click/change/keyup. Then reusing the item via getItem on your result page...